# Problems with MessageBox and MB_HELP

Tags: c++, message, builder, vcl

I am working with C++ Builder and I want to work with MessageBox and the clickables "OK" and "Help". When the user presses "Help", a new form should be opened. So here is my problem:

While using MessageBox and the command with MB_HELP, the Buttons "ok" and "Help" will be displayed. But when pressing Help the compiler won't do anything, he only does something and returns 1 when i am pressing Ok Button.

btw. i am with VCL-Formapplication.

Thanks for your help :)

```
if (Application->MessageBox("Die maximale Temperatur von 30°Grad darf nicht 
überschritten werden",
    "Warnung", MB_HELP | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION) == IDOK);
         {
            ///setting values///
         }           
else Form1->Show();
```

Comment: Provide the code, please.

Comment: Inside the question.

Comment: _"But when pressing Help the compiler won't do anything"_ - what should the compiler do when you're already running the program? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to open a new form, where there are further information for the user by clicking the help button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it now.

If you want to check several conditions on the same result, you can assign it to a variable first. MessageBox returns an `int`, so:

```
int choice = Application->MessageBox("Die maximale Temperatur von 30°Grad darf nicht überschritten werden",
                                     "Warnung", MB_HELP | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
if (choice == IDOK) {
    /// setting values///
}
else if (choice == IDHELP) {
    else Form1->Show();
}
```

You can of course use a `switch` statement. If you need information about these things, see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Thanks for your respond :) minutes ago i come to the same solution and it works, thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)